# Popping all of the elements of a list

Tags: python

I'm learning the basics of Python and with a `for`loop, I am trying to use the `pop` method in order to remove all of the elements of my list. To my surprise anyway, some elements remain and I don't know why.

```
thelist = ['CompSci', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'Art', 'Physics', 'Sports', 'Economics', 'Biology']


for items in thelist:
    thelist.pop(0)

print(thelist)
```

I expect to end up with an empty set, but the actual output is the last 4 elements `['Physics', 'Sports', 'Economics', 'Biology']`.

Comment: You're modifying the list whilst iterating, so you're truncating the list and when by the time it reaches the 4th element it's reached the end of the list

Comment: @Devesh it's not a dupe, the OP wants to know why the list truncates to half it's original size

Comment: @EdChum it's a dupe of *something* for sure

Comment: @Chris_Rands probably, can't find it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's print the item and list while iterating

```py
In [5]: thelist = ['CompSci', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'Art', 'Physics', 'Sports', 'Economics', 'Biology'] 
   ...:  
   ...:  
   ...: for items in thelist: 
   ...:     print(items) 
   ...:     thelist.pop(0) 
   ...:     print(thelist) 
   ...:  
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                      
CompSci
['Math', 'Chemistry', 'Art', 'Physics', 'Sports', 'Economics', 'Biology']
Chemistry
['Chemistry', 'Art', 'Physics', 'Sports', 'Economics', 'Biology']
Physics
['Art', 'Physics', 'Sports', 'Economics', 'Biology']
Economics
['Physics', 'Sports', 'Economics', 'Biology']
```

So every time the loop runs you go one item forward, and also remove one item from the list, so you iterate the list 4 times instead of 8

Answer (score 0):

That's because list is mutable object. You just can't remove items while iterating through it and get the result you expect.
Use this:

```
list_len = len(thelist)
for _ in range(list_len):
    thelist.pop(0)
```

Comment: you can remove item while iterating, it just not advised as best practise, since the behaviour may surprise you

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with Ron Serruya's answer and I've got a very similar example, only printing the list twice for extra clarity.

A rule of thumb that can be applied is to never try to drop items from any iterator. This can be difficult to debug in my opinion.

```
thelist = ['CompSci', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'Art', 'Physics', 'Sports', 'Economics', 'Biology']

for items in thelist:
    print(items)
    print(thelist)
    thelist.pop(0)
    print(thelist)
```